# React-bootstrap :- is it possible to have MenuItem inside Popover

Tags: reactjs, react-bootstrap

is it possible to have MenuItem inside Popover component and still retain style. Right now I get menuitem (without style), when I just use MenuItem component. When I wrap it inside  , nothing get visible.

```
<Overlay
  show={this.state.isOpen}
  target={this.state.target}
  placement="bottom"
  container={this}
>
  <Popover
    id="profilePopover"
    title={`Hello ${givenName || ''}${surname || ''}`}
  >
    <strong>Holy guacamole!</strong> Check this info.
    <Clearfix>
      <ul className="dropdown-menu open">
        <MenuItem>link</MenuItem>
      </ul>
    </Clearfix>
  </Popover>
</Overlay>
```

Answer (score 0):

You are returning more than 1 item inside the popover class.

```
<Overlay
  show={this.state.isOpen}
  target={this.state.target}
  placement="bottom"
  container={this}
>
  <Popover
    id="profilePopover"
    title={`Hello ${givenName || ''}${surname || ''}`}
  >
 {
<div>
<strong>Holy guacamole!</strong> Check this info.
<Clearfix>
<ul className="dropdown-menu open" style={{display:"block", position: "relative"}}>
   <MenuItem>Test</MenuItem>
   <MenuItem>Test2</MenuItem>
</ul>
</Clearfix>                                                                        </div>                                                                           }
  </Popover>
</Overlay>
```

and it got something to do with the classname "dropdown-menu open" try add a style in it

Answer (score 0):

Thanks guys, I created custom popover element, and threw some custom .css, and I can see menuItem inside popover. Though I am yet to correct arrowOffset values and top alignment not working... separate question for them.

```
        <Overlay
          show={this.state.isOpen}
          target={this.state.target}
          container={this}
          placement="bottom"
          arrowOffsetTop="-6px;"
          arrowOffsetLeft="79%;"
        >
          <PopoverAligned
            links={links}
            givenName={givenName}
            surname={surname}
            greetingText={greetingText}
          />
        </Overlay>


const PopoverAligned = props => (
  <Popover
    id="profilePopover"
    title={`${props.greetingText} ${props.givenName || ''} ${props.surname || ''}`}
    className="dropdown-menu open"
    placement="bottom"
    style={{ top: '43px;', left: '-100px' }}
  >
    {
      props.links.map(link => (
        <li className="menuitem">
          <a href={link.url} target={link.target} className="dropdown-link">
            {link.title}
          </a>
        </li>
    ))
    }
  </Popover>
);
```